# Make <select> options panel show as an accordion not as a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i'm trying to make a  tag options show as an accoridion, not as a dropdown, but it doesn´t work like that.

i have this

```
<select onclick="document.getElementById('options');" onChange="accordion(this.value)" name="search_type" style="margin-right:10px; margin-top:2px;" class="button-white">

<div id="options">
    <option selected="selected" value="Precipitación">Precipitación +</option>    
    <option value="veggies_search">Humedad</option>
    <option value="animals_search">Precipitación</option>
    <option value="all_search">Presión Atmosférica</option>
    <option value="all_search">Temperatura</option>
    <option value="all_search">Velocidad Viento</option>
</div>

  </select>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function accordion(value){

  }
</script>
```

i´m using select tag because i need the name of the option selected displayed on the trigger button.

```js
function accordion(value){
    
}
```

```html
<select onclick="document.getElementById('options');" onChange="accordion(this.value)" name="search_type" style="margin-right:10px; margin-top:2px;" class="button-white">
    
<div id="options">
    <option selected="selected" value="Precipitación">Precipitación +</option>    
    <option value="veggies_search">Humedad</option>
    <option value="animals_search">Precipitación</option>
    <option value="all_search">Presión Atmosférica</option>
    <option value="all_search">Temperatura</option>
    <option value="all_search">Velocidad Viento</option>
</div>

  </select>
```

Hope you can help me. Thank you so much

Comment: You cannot put a div element inside of a select element...only option and optgroup elements.

Comment: I would advice your follow this link step by step on how to code accordion. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Comment: For an accordion, you should be using either radio buttons with labels or checkboxes with labels (depending on whether you want to have multiple panes open at once).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `div` is not a valid child of a `select`. You're going to need to use some divs and some js to achieve what you're looking to do. Something like the following:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
        to highlight the button that controls the panel */
        this.classList.toggle("active");

        /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}

var options = document.getElementsByClassName("option");

for(var o = 0; o < options.length; o++) {
  options[o].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   this.parentElement.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = this.dataset.value;

    /* alert(e.target.dataset.value);  */
  })
}
```

```css
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
.accordion, .option  {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
.active, .accordion:hover, .option:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
.panel {
    padding: 0 18px 0 0;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.option {
  padding: 9px 18px;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Precipitación +</button>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="option" data-value="Humedad">Humedad</div>
  <div class="option" data-value="Presión Atmosférica">Presión Atmosférica</div>
  <div class="option" data-value="Temperatura">Temperatura</div>
  <div class="option" data-value="Velocidad Viento">Velocidad Viento</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Ghostrydr! Thanks for your answer it works but the only problem is that the selected option is shown as an alert, and has to be shown on the button replacing the previous selection name. I'm trying to do it by replacing this part  **var options[o].addEventListener('click', function(e, r) {
 document.getElementsByClassName("accordion").html(e.target.dataset.value); **    But it doesn´t work :/

Comment: I've updated the solution to match your requirements

Comment: Wow Thank you so much really Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Just a quick question over the accordion that yu helped me with, how can i make taht when they click another tab it closes the curret active one so that they only can see one opened at a time? Thanks

Comment: @TaniaMartínez are you able to use something like jQuery? Or do you need to stick with vanilla js?

Comment: Hi @Ghostrydr mm i´m super new in both i have very little knowledge on how to use them :/ ...